# Getting an error trying to add a new Web Service reference to my c# project in VS2019

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2019

I am not able to add new Web Service references to my C# project. Visual Studio 2019 fails to open the dialog to add the Web Service.

When I launch the Add Connected Services option in my .NET 4.7.2 C# project, and try to add a SOAP Web Service reference using the "Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider", instead of showing the dialog to add the Web Service reference, it shows an alert message with the following error:

The connected services component 'Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider' failed: The project reference specification 'Microsoft.Csharp' does not have a file path.

BTW, even though this is a regular .NET framework assembly project, I am using the new .NET SDK style project file. Also, it works fine for the first web service reference that I add. Any further attempts to add more web service references cause this error!

Does anyone know whey this would happen?

Comment: Are you talking about the old version of the service based on the .net framework2.0 web service? It is hide in Add Service Reference menu (Advanced menu->add web reference). For WCF service/asp.net xml web service(asmx), we could use the Add Service Reference menu.

Comment: VS2019 does not have Add Service Reference menu anymore. Now they have Add Connected Service menu. But the problem is that I can add the service reference successfully in a new project. Just cannot do any more additions after that.

Comment: Yes, for Netframework project. right-click the Connected services, then Add service reference. On my side, I could add service reference multiple times. I suggest could clean the project and re-add it.

Comment: Hey, how did you resolve this?

Comment: have you sorted out this. I got the same issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I am using VS2019 16.7.5 currently and hit this issue, not being very familiar with all the ins and outs. I hit a number of sites in finding out about this issue - and one that said it had been an earlier bug in version 16.1.
After Adding the Reference - which in my case is to an existing project with an existing service reference.

I added a Controller - for a Web API 2 call -  it started giving me the errors.
I have to write a REST API to call a SOAP service that is blocked by a firewall.
I commented out the method - it would build - uncomment just the signature and it would not.

I found by commenting out the signature (no methods in the class) I could compile - and if I then used the right click of the servicereference and clicked on the Update Service Reference - it generated the reference - and I could browse to it in the Object Browser.
Now the controller needs a reference to that Service and then it will have Objects and Methods from the Reference to develop the correct service objects to do the work

Update: I had to add Another service and again it would not show up - and this time the solution was a little different - I added the service with the WSDL, and did the above and when it would not show - I did an Update Service Reference - still no show - but this time I closed Visual Studio and reopened it - and there was my object browser definition. Then I created My Controller and could use the objects.

Answer (score 0):

I had to put the solution's name plus a dot in front of it. For example:
Solution is called 'Solution1'
Service reference is called 'Service1'
then call it with Solution1.Service1.... instead of only Service1...